# How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, uri, navigation

I have a Link field named `field_my_link` (machine name).

Within a Twig template I can get the link's URL value with this:

```
{{ node.field_my_link.uri }}
```

If inside the Link's URL there is an *external* URL, e.g. `http://example.com` it works good.

But, if inside the Link's URL there is stored an *internal* URL, e.g. `"/node/11"`, I get a value like this:

```
"internal:/node/11"
```

with the "`internal:`" prefix.

How can I get the *valid* URL?

For example, if the link's URL is "`http://example.com`" I want "`http://example.com`" (this already works), if the link's URL is "`/node/11`" I want the relative URL "`/node/11`", if the link's URL is "`<front>`" I want the URL "`/`", etc.

---

**EDIT**

I can get the value I want within a PHP preprocess function, using this:

```
$url = $variables['node']->get('field_my_link')->first()->getUrl();
```

How can I access the same value within the Twig template?

I know I can do this within the preprocess function:

```
$variables['my_url'] = $url;
```

Then access the url within Twig using `{{ my_url }}`, but I would avoid to write a preprocess function each time I have a link field.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your PHP from your latest edit would translate into twig like this:

```
{{ node.field_my_link.0.url }}
```

This works like this, `0` returns the first item of the field item list, `url` gets the url object and because twig will cast this object as a string this will call the magic method toString() and will output the url as a string value.

You only need to use `url`, because twig looks automatically for the method `getxyz()` if there is no property with that name `xyz`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I make a test with this function. Do you know if can I use this function also on links' URIs? What happen if `node.field_my_link.uri` is an external url like `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: I tried with `file_url(node.field_my_link.uri)`, and if `node.field_my_link.uri` is `"http://www.example.com"` it works (it leaves the url unchanged), but if `node.field_my_link.uri` is `"internal:/"` the function returns `"/internal%3A/"` (instead of `"/"`)..

Comment: I just saw your edit.. Sadly it doesn't works, the code `node.field_my_link.entity.uri.value` returns a null value.. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Andrea, I edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it works. The syntax is a bit scary, but it does its job.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as "solution" as the file_url() function works just with files and not with link fields. The thread starter asked for the raw url output of a "link field".

Comment: I don't believe this approach works with {% if content.field.0.url %} because there's no implicit 'request to cast to string'. Is there a way to cast the variable to get the desired output for string comparison?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `field_link.0.url` throws a syntax error. I had to use `field_link[0].url` instead.

Comment: To answer NikLP above, if you need the string in a conditional, you can specifically call the toString method to get a string such as `{% if content.field.0.url.toString %}`

Comment: For me, it had to be: {{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}

Answer (score 30):

You can access the render array element directly, in your case:

```
{{ node.field_my_link[0]['#url'] }}
```

Comment: It appears this is now the correct answer.

Comment: This one worked for me.

Comment: works with d9 paragraphs

Answer (score 24):

You have to cover both cases: external and internal URLs.

First let's check if the URL is **external** and simply print its `*.uri`.

Else if it's **internal** we have to wire its route name and parameters through Drupal's [`path($name, $parameters, $options)`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates) function.

```
{% if node.field_link.0.url.external %}
  <a href="{{ node.field_link.uri }}">
    {{ node.field_link.title }}
  </a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{{ path(node.field_link.0.url.routeName, node.field_link.0.url.routeParameters) }}">
    {{ node.field_link.title }}
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed: get the url from a link field as a string:
`{% set url = path(node.field_link.0.url.routeName, node.field_link.0.url.routeParameters) %}`
Then I can create a custom link:`
`<a href="{{ url }}" class="mycustomclass">custom link text</a>`
No preprocess needed and no need to go via content.field_link, so no  need to do anything in the 'Manage display' for the link field just to get the url.

Comment: I believe you could just call `node.field_link.0.url.toString` as `toString` would handle the internal/external logic for you.

Comment: `external` is now protected property, hence not accessible, use `isExternal()` function.

Answer (score 19):

I had to do this on a Link Field in a Block. This worked well:

```
{{ content.field_my_link[0]['#url']|render }}
```

Comment: It is also fine to use `{{ content.field_my_link[0]['#url'] }}` without *render*, as in twig template, render array are automatically rendered when printed.

Answer (score 16):

you can also use something like the following, it all depends of the type of object you are extracting and the field name, In my case it was a paragraph with a field named field_link and the following worked:

```
{{ paragraph.field_link.get(0).getUrl().toString() }}
```

Comment: You are the man today my friend! Look at this craziness!  I added a page_link field on one of my taxonomies.  So i have to do this: 

{% set page_url = content.field_category.0['#options'].entity.field_page_link.get(0).getURL().toString() %}

Now it outputs the url instead of the node ID, thank you!

Comment: It worked for me to, this is the solution!

Comment: You saved me again today! This time a paragraph field and getting the full internal link url.

{% set full_link_url = content.field_content_block.0['#paragraph'].field_external_link.get(0).getUrl().toString() %} - BTW, this worked in a node template.

Comment: For me this one works for internal & external links

Comment: Thank you.  So what are Twig and Drupal doing internally when we say {{ paragraph.field_link.url that is *not* that?  /headdesk

(To be clear, Israel's code works, and it is Drupal failing to do that by default that is flabbergastering me.)

Comment: This is the short version of your code, which works for me, too: 
`{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url.toString }}`

Answer (score 11):

I know it's an old post but with the last version of Drupal 8 (8.6) you can directly display the url for both version (external and internal):

```
node.field_link.0.url
```

And if you need to know if the link is external or not (for my case it was for the target), you can use that:

```
node.field_link.0.url.external
```

Example:

```
<a href="{{ node.field_link.0.url }}" title="Title" target="{{ node.field_link.0.url.external ? '_blank' : '_self' }}"
```

Comment: I like your usage of target =  _self for *internal* and *external* _blank. It improves the UX.

Answer (score 4):

In paragraph, to get the link url and link name -

```
<a href="{{ content.FIELD_LINK_NAME[0]['#url']|render }}">
   {{ content.FIELD_LINK_NAME[0]['#title']|render }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following on from a previous answer - Twig tweak is my goto for future proofing some of the cryptic syntax used in the past.

{{ node.field_link_to_purchase | file_url }} - this work for me on the latest version at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

I *know* it's horrible, but if nothing else works:

`{{ link|replace({'internal:':''}) }}`

**My situation**: accessing a Link field via an overridden views template: `views-view-fields.html.twig`

I had to get the variable from:

`row._entity.field_machine_name.value.0.uri`

(I gave up trying to use the `fields` variable, you can seemingly get a *.content* property out of that, but not much else)

*….field_machine_name.value* is just a flat array, which only has a `uri` key, NOT `url`, and the filters mentioned in other answers (toString(), render etc.) simply don't seem to work here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this.
This example exclude the use of the Title field.

```
{% set link_url = content.field_link.0['#url'] %}
{% set link = link_url ? link_url : content.field_link.0['#title'] %}

{% if link %}
  {{ link.toString() }}
{% endif %}
```

Possible results

```
# Input ---------------- Output -----------
# This is a node (23)    /relative/url
# <front>                /
# https://drupal.org     https://drupal.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is much simpler solution using https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value module

```
<a href="{{ content.FIELD_LINK_NAME|field_value|first['#url']|render }}">
  {{ content.FIELD_LINK_NAME|field_value|first['#title'] }}
</a>
```

This will work for both internal and external links.

Comment: Better if you use this: ```{{ content.field_my_link|field_raw('uri') }}```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add some classes to my link. field_url is a link field. I didn't have *content* in the Twig context.

`{{ node.field_url[0] }}` gives me a \Drupal\Core\Url object.

`{% set link = node.field_url[0] | view %}` This is a filter from the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. It returns a render array.

I can now output my link like this:

```
<a href="{{ link['#url'] | render }}" class="featured-link featured-link--small">{{ link['#title'] | render }}</a>
```

Twig tweak is amazing. [Here is a link to the cheat sheet](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md) where you can see all the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mix of the next solutions for wrap content in a link within paragraph entity and to add target attribute:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/273090/5501
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/286693/5501

```
{% set link = paragraph.field_link.get(0) %}
{% set url = link.getUrl().toString() %}

{# prevent having urls built from special types "<button>", "<nolink>", but allow "<front>" #}
{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}" target="{{ link.url.external ? '_blank' : '_self' }}">
{% endif %}
    content here...
{% if url %}
  </a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Supplementary answer**

The [answer above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199263/1082) can be applied to a Drupal Paragraph:

```
{{ node.field_link.0.url }}
```

...if you replace the entity type `name` node with `paragraph` as so:

```
{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }}
```

Where in your site, you would have created a Paragraph with a field called link - which would have machine name field_link.

I found that the above `{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }}` renders to the URL when used link this:

```
<a href="{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }}">{{ paragraph.field_link.0.title }}</a>
```

This works for both internal and external URLs. I tested:

- `#our-team` - a URL fragment for use with an `<a` anchor
- `https://bbc.co.uk`

I have defined in the paragraph instance I added in a entity reference node - the usual process for adding paragraphs, of course.

For my purpose, I wanted to create a Call-to-action (CTA) button, using a paragraph, here is all my code below to do that, which illustrates how I've used the twig link and title.

I enclose the whole paragraph markup with the with `<a href="{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }`... ...`/>`

And put the link text, the `title` inside: `{{ paragraph.field_link.0.title }}`

file:

```
web/themes/custom/my_theme/templates/paragraphs/paragraph--call-to-action.html.twig
```

code:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}
{% block paragraph %}

  <div class="mysite-cta-outer">
  <a href="{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }}">
    <span{{ attributes.addClass(classes).addClass('mysite-cta-fixed') }}>
      {% block content %}
        {{ paragraph.field_link.0.title }}
      {% endblock %}
    </span>
  </a>
  </div>

{% endblock paragraph %}
```

file:

```
web/themes/custom/my_theme/css/styles/_cta.css
```

code:

```
.mysite-cta-outer {
  padding-top: 1.0em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.field--name-field-main-call-to-action-area {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}


.mysite-cta-fixed {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
  width: 15em;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

span.mysite-cta-fixed a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


span.mysite-cta a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.mysite-cta {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, a comment about, `url` vs `uri` as this has been talked about in other answers.  For me, as you can see from my code, url is what I use, in the `<a href="{{ paragraph.field_link.0.url }}">`...

`vardumper` util  (from Drupal module `twig_vardumper` ) shows the following for `url` and `url`:

`{{ vardumper( paragraph.field_link.0.url ) }}`

- output :-

[image: output of vardumper( paragraph.field_link.0.url )]

^ that initially put me off using `url` because it was a `Url` class and not text which I assumed had to be output but it is the right one for outputting the URL.  So what seems to happen is that twig renders this Url object as text automatically.

And here's `uri` output

`{{ vardumper( paragraph.field_link.0.uri ) }}`

output:-

```
^ "internal:#our-story"
```

Which I didn't use for aforementioned explanation.

This took me a few hours for troubleshooting so I'm grateful for the other answers here, though a bit despairing that there are multiple ways to do it, which potentially causes confusion, also somewhat demoralising to spend a lot of time on something so small. The 'dot' notation here is still something mysterious to me as to how to use it fully, and it shouldn't be. I hope to encounter a definitive guide to get results quickly with this. These answers here do help in the meantime!