# How to get the value / URL of a Link field in a Twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I have a custom block Type with a Link field called "field_link" (for internal links only). Within my block Twig template I want to extract the URL of the link field. How can I do that? I read some post with similar problems, but none of the solutions seems to work so far.

What I tried so far:

```
{{ file_url(content.field_link.uri) }}
{{ file_url(content.field_link.0.url) }}
```

I only get "/" but there should be "/node/1"...

This is my standard block template:

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>   
      {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if label %}
        <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
      {% endif %}
      {{ title_suffix }}
      {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
      {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template)

Comment: The accepted answer in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template does not work for custom content blocks

Answer (score 6):

You can get the URL and the value (text) this way:

```
{{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}

{{ content.field_link.0['#title'] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to use file_url(), but you can use `{{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}` as described in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499554/extract-url-title-from-link-field-in-drupal-8) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

`item.content['#url']` gives a render array :

[image: getting the render array of link in drupal]

However, if you need to extract only the URL which can be anything like frontpage, a node in your site or external, you need to use the `.toString()` utility.

`item.content['#url'].toString()`

[image: get image URL from link field twig]

Title can be accessed from `item.content['#title']`

Remember that it's all inside the loop:

```
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>
        {{ dsm((item.content['#title'])) }}
        {{ dsm((item.content['#url'].toString())) }}
        <a href="{{ item.content['#url'].toString() }}">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most templates (node, paragraph,...) you can access raw field values using
`{{ entity_type.field_name.0.value }}`. Sadly this does not work block templates. To make it work for custom content blocks you need to add a preprocess function:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(array &$variables) {
  if ($variables['base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    $variables['block_content'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
  }
}
```

Now you can access your fields using `{{ block_content.field_name.0.value }}` (in case of link fields use `{{ block_content.field_name.0.url }}` [as described here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template))

Answer (score -1):

This code will be work properly for printing separate **URL** and **Title** of the link field in twig.

```
{{ content.field_link.0.['#url'] }}

{{ content.field_link.0.['#title'] }}
```