# How to get the specific field raw data in node.html.twig

Tags: theming, entities, navigation

I am using link field in a couple of content types, but when I am trying get url from node.html.twig with content.field_my_link_field and have tried some suggestions like `content.field_my_link_field.uri`, `content.field_my_link_field.content|raw`, `content.field_my_link_field.content|striptags`, `content.field_my_link_field.0` but all return `null`.
Is there any possible solution to getting raw url from link field in (preferably) twig or any other way.

I am using Drupal 8.

Comment: check this URL, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template