# Get path/url/uri of Entity reference field to content in a Twig template?

Tags: entities, uri

I have a Entity reference field which links to internal content/node.

I can get the title with {{ node.field_related_project_internal.entity.label }}

But how can I get the raw path/url/uri of the linked content/node?
The soloutions for a Link Field to not work here:
[How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template)

Comment: `{{ node.field_related_project_internal.entity.0.url }}` not working? Can u do `{{ dump(node.field_related_project_internal.entity) }}` & check u r getting ur field or not?

Comment: {{ node.field_related_project_internal.entity.0.url }} is not working / no output. {{ dump(node.field_related_project_internal.entity) }} gives me a blank page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The url is not an entity field, so you can't access it directly. Also the entity methods to generate url/links are not accessible in Twig because of the sandbox policies. You can build a path though, if you have the id of the referenced node:

```
{% if not node.field_ref.isempty %}
  {{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node':  node.field_ref.entity.id}) }}
{% endif %}
```

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

Comment: It works and I understand now. Thank you for the explanation!