# Using replace in my twig returns a blank

Tags: theming

I have what I think is a rather simple statement here

```
{{ (content.field_url.0)|replace("http://","") }}
```

but then I get an error

> Warning: strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   twig_replace_filter() (line 482 of
>   vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php).
>   twig_replace_filter(Array, 'http://', '') (Line: 57)

---

Changing it up a little

```
{{ (content.field_url.0)|replace('http://',"") }}
```

and then I get this error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension() (line 148
>   of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser.php).

---

One more change up

```
{{ (content.field_url.0)|replace({'http://':""}) }}
```

and this returns nothing, nada, no value at all.

Comment: You have to dig a little bit deeper: `{{ content.field_url[0]['#url'] }}`. You might also need to [distinguish between internal and external URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/247807/15055).

Comment: Since you want to remove characters at the beginnig of your string, you might want to give a try to the "trim" filter :
    {{ content.field_url.0|trim('http://', 'left') }}

Comment: Always easier to preprocess than to operate on render arrays.