# Get Link value in Media entity

Tags: theming, hooks, media

We have a `Media` type called `Documents` that has a `Link` field called `field_link`. We need to obtain the URL (external or internal) from the field so that we can use to wrap block elements inside of a `<a>` tag in our twig templates. All works fine when the link is an external URL, but when linking to an internal page, the following code does not work in our `mymodule_preprocess_media` hook.

**How can I obtain both the internal and external link within the `field_link` field inside of the `mymodule_preprocess_media` hook?**

This is what we have tried, but only works for `external` links.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  $media_entity = $variables['elements']['#media'];
  $link = $media_entity->get('field_link')->first();

  // This works for external, but not internal
  $link_value = $link->getUrl()->getUri();

  $variables['custom_var'] = [
    'link_value' => $link_value,
  ];
}
```

**`media--document.html.twig`**

```
<a href="{{ custom_var['link_value'] }}">
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
</a>
```

When using `ksm($link->getUrl())`, we find that the `uri` value is `NULL` when the link is internal.

**Goals:**

1. Get the internal link (absolute) using `hook_preprocess_media`
2. Get the external link using `hook_preprocess_media`

Comment: Just a guess: `if (is_null($link->getUrl()->getUri())) { $link_value = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri($link); }`

Comment: Normally it doesn't matter if you have a field object or a field item, but for the Link field it does, use `->first()` and then it should work, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template

Comment: @4k4 adding the `->first()` did solve part of the issue, but it was still having an issue with `internal` links so i followed the solution provided by `berramou`

Comment: Yes, the key is the url object. Once you've got it from the field item all problems are solved. Then the possible solutions are countless, because all url handling in Drupal is built around this object. See the answers in the linked question and here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_media().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_media(&$variables) {
  $media_entity = $variables['elements']['#media'];
  /**
   * @note: in case your field not multiple, otherwise loop through the field.
   */
  $link = $media_entity->get('field_link')->first();
  if ($link->isExternal()) {
    //- External.
    $link_value = $link->getValue()['uri'];
  }
  else {
    //- internal.
    $link_value = $link->getUrl()->toString();
  }
  $variables['custom_var'] = [
    'link_value' => $link_value,
  ];
}
```

Comment: this lead to my solution so it is being marked as such. if someone wants to get the absolute URL for `internal` links then they replace `$link->getUrl()->toString()` with `URL::fromRoute($link->getUrl()->getRouteName(), $link->getUrl()->getRouteParameters(), ['absolute' => true])->toString();`. Not sure if you want to update the answer to reflect this, but adding it just in case as a comment.