# Date and links formatting in node template

Tags: theming

Drupal 8.x

I have 2 quick questions. I have the following node template `node--briefing--teaser.html.twig`

```
<div>
  <span>{{ date }}</span>
  <span>{{ label }}</span>
  <a href="{{ content.links.uri }}"></a>
</div>
```

Now the questions are:

- How can I format the date to the following `d/m/Y`
- How can I get the URI of the read more field (links)

With a normal link field you can simply do `content.my_link.0['#url']` to get this but that doesn't seem to be the case with the node links field.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Hudri I already tried those answers and none of them gave any output. I guess the Links field is formatted differently ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you meant a "real" URL field. I never use that weirdo pseudo  "Links" field.

Comment: If it is of any help, you can get the URL to the node full view using `{{ url }}`, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x

Comment: Yeah I just had to use the URL attribute in twig to get what I want.

Comment: @Hudri do you happen to know how to format the date attribute in the twig file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the date formating: {{ date.value|date('U')|format_date('custom', 'j/m/Y') }}

For the URI investigate the data structure with [twig vardumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper).