# How to get the URL of remote video inserted by media field in block or paragraph twig?

Tags: theming, media, uri

How to get the URL of remote video inserted by media field in block or paragraph twig?
I am using the paragraphs module to create video galleries from youtube videos. When I use `{{ content.video_gallery }}` it's working and showing the youtube video thumbnail but I want to show this video in a popup for which I have written a code in which I need only the URL of the youtube video.
I am searching for two days I found solutions for image and video but no solution found for remote video URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template)

Comment: No, it's about getting URL from a node link field and I am looking for the Embedded URL of the media field.