# How to get the url of a link field in field.html.twig

Tags: theming, 9

Inside the **field--link.html.twig** file, I'm trying to output the url from a link field like so:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}><a class="button" href="{{ item.content.uri }}">Apply Now</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried the following to get the url, and nothing seems to work.

- item.content.uri,
- item.content.uri,
- item.content.url,
- item.content.0.url,
- item.content.url | render,
- item.content.0['#url'],
  etc ...

How can I get the url from my link field?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried like `link['#url'].uri` this?

Comment: This seems to be the answer. {{ item.content['#url'].uri  }}

May I ask where this information is kept?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template)