# Get MenuLinkContent object values

Tags: 8, theming

get title and link of a menu link object in. I am trying to get title and link of a MenuLinkContent object and below is my code. I want to get title and link value. How I can get the title and Link url without foreach. something like- menu_content[]->title and  menu_content[]->link

Defined name spaces

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu;
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;
```

Code in

```
 function build(){

       $menu_content = current(\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(array('id' => 123)));
  $menu_content_title =  $menu_content->values;
  \Drupal::logger('module_name')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($menu_content, TRUE) . '</code></pre>' );
    }
```

output:

```
Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent Object
(
[insidePlugin:protected] => 
[values:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 123
            )

        [revision_id] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 124
            )

        [bundle] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => menu_link_content
            )

        [uuid] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 8930a948-921e-4fasddb-be34-c98bcd6ae4c3
            )

        [langcode] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => en
            )

        [revision_user] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 
            )

        [revision_created] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 1626345445
            )

        [revision_log_message] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 
            )

        [revision_default] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 1
            )

        [isDefaultRevision] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 1
            )

        [enabled] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 1
            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Example title
            )

        [description] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 
            )

        [link] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [uri] => https://www.example.com
                        [title] => 
                        [options] => Array
                            (
                                [fa_icon] => 
                                [fa_icon_prefix] => fa
                                [fa_icon_tag] => i
                                [fa_icon_appearance] => before
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [class] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [target] => _blank
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Got Title `$title = $menu_content->getTitle();` but Url not getting
After apply code: `$url = $menu_content->get('link')->first()->getUrl();`

```
Drupal\Core\Url Object
(
[urlGenerator:protected] => 
[urlAssembler:protected] => 
[accessManager:protected] => 
[routeName:protected] => 
[routeParameters:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[options:protected] => Array
    (
        [fa_icon] => 
        [fa_icon_prefix] => fa
        [fa_icon_tag] => i
        [fa_icon_appearance] => before
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [class] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [target] => _blank
            )

        [external] => 1
    )

[external:protected] => 1
[unrouted:protected] => 1
[uri:protected] => https://www.example.com
[internalPath:protected] => 
[_serviceIds:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_entityStorages:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you give your use case?

Comment: @Jaypan I written code in file and static title and urls but I want to call the title and url from the menu. So  [title] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Example title
            )
   [link] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [uri] => https://www.example.com
                     }
                  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us why you've loaded the entity. You usually can get this information directly from the menu link plugin via `getUrlObject()`, without knowing whether there is an underlying entity or the menu link is defined differently, for example in a YAML file.

The entity has a Link field with the name `link`:

```
$url = $menu_content->get('link')->first()->getUrl();
```

See [How to get the valid URL of a Link field from within a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template).

The title is available for both, plugin or entity, by the same method:

```
$title = $menu_content->getTitle();
```

Comment: $url = $menu_content->get('link')->first()->getUrl(); is not working. Please check the output in the question

Comment: The output looks OK to me. You can use the URL object as it is, to build a link and render it in a Twig template. Convert it to a string with `$url->toString()`, but only if you need it now and don't want to render it.