Access child paragraph fields in parent field - How to get link field url value of child paragraph in parent paragraph
I have a field of type "link" named "field_link" in a child paragraph, I'm unable to get this field value in the parent paragraph using the below:
{{content.field_childpara.field_link.0['#url'].value}}
but I can access a field of type "text" from child paragraph in a parent paragraph like below:
{{content.field_childpara.field_ctitle.0.value}}
Any help is appreciated

There is no issue with fields other than type "Link". I could not find any answer and my code is also not working. So seeking some suggestions on accessing "Field of type Link" in parent paragraph

Then please check these answers: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199262/15055
